# azure ad b2c to show SignIn button on Signup Page

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

created a custom signup policy(SignUp is default form for my application) to first show signup form but now need to add button which takes user to signin if they already have account.

Something like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLxZd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Adding buttons not supported by the Azure AD B2C service itself with the exception of the unifiedssp and idpselection screens. The screen shown in your image is the self-asserted one. To get around this, you can add this via custom JavaScript on your [UI templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui).

The self-injected button should be able to utilise the `history.back()` method.

Comment: When I tried to add this custom html https://xaw90b2bsa.blob.core.windows.net/root/Untitled-1.html to the self asserted content definition getting below error

https://sample.powerappsportals.com/Account/Login/ExternalAuthenticationFailed

sign in failed

Comment: Enabling devtools and inspecting the network payload will give you the proper error sent from B2C to your power app.
Make sure [scripts are enabled for your journey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout)